# What is the Standard way to Parse different Dates passed as Query-Params to the REST API?

Tags: java, rest, java-8, java-time

I am working on a REST API which supports Date as a query param. Since it is Query param it will be String. Now the Date can be sent in the following formats in the QueryParams:

```
yyyy-mm-dd[(T| )HH:MM:SS[.fff]][(+|-)NNNN]
```

It means following are valid dates:

```
2017-05-05 00:00:00.000+0000
2017-05-05 00:00:00.000
2017-05-05T00:00:00
2017-05-05+0000
2017-05-05
```

Now to parse all these different date-times i am using `Java8 datetime` api. The code is as shown below:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().parseCaseInsensitive()
    .append(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd[[ ][['T'][ ]HH:mm:ss[.SSS]][Z]"))
    .toFormatter(); 
LocalDateTime localDateTime = null;
LocalDate localDate = null;
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of(ZoneOffset.UTC.getId());
Date date = null;

try {
    localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(datetime, formatter);
    date = Date.from(localDateTime.atZone(zoneId).toInstant());
} catch (Exception exception) {
    System.out.println("Inside Excpetion");
    localDate = LocalDate.parse(datetime, formatter);
    date = Date.from(localDate.atStartOfDay(zoneId).toInstant());
}
```

As can be seens from the code I am using `DateTimeFormatter` and appending a pattern. Now I am first trying to parse date as `LocalDateTime` in the `try-block` and if it throws an exception for cases like `2017-05-05` as no time is passed, I am using a `LocalDate` in the `catch block`.

The above approach is giving me the solution I am looking for but my questions are that is this the standard way to deal with date sent as String and is my approach is in line with those standards?

Also, If possible what is the other way I can parse the different kinds of date (shown as the Valid dates above) except some other straightforward solutions like using an Array list and putting all the possible formats and then using for-loop trying to parse the date?

Comment: The fact that you are expecting 5 different formats in one field it is not standard itself. You could probably append a different formatter for each format.

Comment: @NiVeR  that means if in the future we are supporting 10 different datetime formats then we require 10 datetime parsers. But with above approach maybe one other datetime parser will cover the remaining datetimes.

Comment: That's why standards exist. You define an interface to your system and if someone wants to use they need to adapt the format. I don't see a gain from accepting all these different formats, in the contrary you must handle all the possible cases making the code messy.

Comment: As REST is defacto a generalization of the Web you can apply the same concepts to it as you do for the Web. I.e. a client would request information on how to submit data, the server would return with a form giving the client any available option to create the actual request and also the information where to send the request to. Therefore the server actually would already define what date-formats it will expect. Of course this does not prevent that clients may try to generate their own version of the request so a check needs to be done on the server none the less

Comment: Is the time of day required to 00:00 if present, and the offset +0000 if present? Or was that just for the sake of the example?

Comment: @OleV.V.  I didnt know you have updated your answer. Waiting for that in order to accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE)
            // time is optional
            .optionalStart()
            .parseCaseInsensitive()
            .appendPattern("[ ]['T']")
            .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME)
            .optionalEnd()
            // offset is optional
            .appendPattern("[xx]")
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.OFFSET_SECONDS, 0)
            .toFormatter();
    for (String queryParam : new String[] {
            "2017-05-05 00:00:00.000+0000",
            "2017-05-05 00:00:00.000",
            "2017-05-05T00:00:00",
            "2017-05-05+0000",
            "2017-05-05",
            "2017-05-05T11:20:30.643+0000",
            "2017-05-05 16:25:09.897+0000",
            "2017-05-05 22:13:55.996",
            "2017-05-05t02:24:01"
    }) {
        Instant inst = OffsetDateTime.parse(queryParam, formatter).toInstant();
        System.out.println(inst);
    }
```

The output from this snippet is:

```
2017-05-05T00:00:00Z
2017-05-05T00:00:00Z
2017-05-05T00:00:00Z
2017-05-05T00:00:00Z
2017-05-05T00:00:00Z
2017-05-05T11:20:30.643Z
2017-05-05T16:25:09.897Z
2017-05-05T22:13:55.996Z
2017-05-05T02:24:01Z
```

The tricks I am using include:

- Optional parts may be included in either `optionalStart`/`optionalEnd` or in `[]` in a pattern. I use both, each where I find it easier to read, and you may prefer differently.
- There are already predefined formatters for date and time of day, so I reuse those. In particular I take advantage of the fact that `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME` already handles optional seconds and fraction of second.
- For parsing into an `OffsetDateTime` to work we need to supply default values for the parts that may be missing in the query parameter. `parseDefaulting` does this.

In your code you are converting to a `Date`. The `java.util.Date` class is long outdated and has a number of design problems, so avoid it if you can. `Instant` will do fine. If you do need a `Date` for a legacy API that you cannot change or don’t want to change just now, convert in the same way as you do in the question.

EDIT: Now defaulting `HOUR_OF_DAY`, not `MILLI_OF_DAY`. The latter caused a conflict when only the millis were missing, but it seems the formatter is happy with just default hour of day when the time is missing.

Comment: If I am specifying a date like `"2017-05-05T11:20:30.643+0000"` I am getting an error saying ` Text 2017-05-05T11:20:30.643+0000 could not be parsed: Conflict found: HourOfDay 11 differs from HourOfDay 0 while resolving  SecondOfDay`. I tried to debug and found that it is caused by `.parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_DAY, 0);` `.parseDefaulting(ChronoField.OFFSET_SECONDS, 0)` But if I remove these then I cannot parse date `2017-05-05`. Could you help in resolving this?

Comment: Sure @Ole V.V. In the mean time I will also try to resolve the issue.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the [DateUtils.parseDate](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/DateUtils.html#parseDate-java.lang.String-java.lang.String...-) which belongs to [commons-lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/).

This method looks like this:

```
public static Date parseDate(String str,
                         String... parsePatterns)
                  throws ParseException
```

Here is the description:

> Parses a string representing a date by trying a variety of different parsers.
>
> The parse will try each parse pattern in turn. A parse is only deemed successful if it parses the whole of the input string. If no parse patterns match, a ParseException is thrown.
>
> The parser will be lenient toward the parsed date.

Comment: IMHO, since you have to specify different `parsePatterns`, I would prefer the approach mentioned in the question as there I can specify one generic parser and can use the same to parse different datetime format.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Configuration
public class DateTimeConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
    /**
     * https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#format-configuring-formatting-globaldatetimeformat
     * @return
     */

    @Bean
    @Override
    public FormattingConversionService mvcConversionService() {
        DefaultFormattingConversionService conversionService = new DefaultFormattingConversionService(false);
        conversionService.addFormatterForFieldAnnotation(new NumberFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory());
// Register JSR-310 date conversion with a specific global format
        DateTimeFormatterRegistrar dateTimeRegistrar = new DateTimeFormatterRegistrar();
        dateTimeRegistrar.setDateTimeFormatter(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
        dateTimeRegistrar.setDateTimeFormatter(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"));
       dateTimeRegistrar.setDateTimeFormatter(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"));
       dateTimeRegistrar.registerFormatters(conversionService);

  // Register date conversion with a specific global format
        DateFormatterRegistrar dateRegistrar = new DateFormatterRegistrar();
        dateRegistrar.setFormatter(new DateFormatter("yyyy-MM-dd"));
        dateRegistrar.setFormatter(new DateFormatter("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
        dateRegistrar.setFormatter(new DateFormatter("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"));
        dateRegistrar.registerFormatters(conversionService);
        return conversionService;
    }
}
```